# Adding command line arguments to PHP script in iframe

Tags: php, html

I'm working on a Google Maps webapp displaying BART train times, and when you click on a pin at a BART station, an infowindow pops up, that has a php script in an iframe that runs, and shows the times that were parsed from BART's XML feed.

What I would like to be able to do, is call the PHP script from the iframe, like it is now, but add command line arguments (I'm not sure if such a thing is even possible).
Here is my code so far that works.

```
    if(end.match(patt1))
           {    
             response.routes[0].legs[0].end_address="Colma BART station<br />"+"Upcoming trains<br />"+'<iframe src="bart1.php" frameborder="0"; width="200" scrolling="yes"    ></iframe>';
           }
```

So, instead of "bart1.php" can I change that too something like "bart1.php -a foo"?
Thanks,
Amanda

Comment: What about `<iframe src="bart1.php?foo=bar" ...>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `$_GET` array.

An example:
`http://www.webapp.com/test.php?stationnumber=4`

Retrieve the station number by doing this:

`$stationnumber = intval($_GET['stationnumber']);` (intval is there if it is supposed to be numerical input)